# How to Optimize this mongoDB Agregation with a Datetime range

Tags: performance, mongodb, optimization

I am having a problem with very slow aggregate commands when I try and use date ranges in mongoDB 3.0.3

First some background:

The collection in question is CDRs (Call detail records) from a VoIP system. There are 337988521 records currently, but my queries only involve a small subset. Here are the counts to give an idea of the scope:

```
db.CDRs.find({"Date" : { $gte : new Date("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z") } }).count()
116114
db.CDRs.find({"Date" : { $gte : new Date("2015-06-10T08:00:00Z") } }).count()
0
```

Here are my indexes:

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "HS4XC.CDRs"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                    "Date" : 1,
                    "CallID" : 1,
                    "TerminationAttempts.Attempt" : 1
            },
            "name" : "Date_1_CallID_1_TerminationAttempts.Attempt_1",
            "ns" : "HS4XC.CDRs"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "Originator" : 1,
                    "TerminationAttempts.Terminator" : 1
            },
            "name" : "Originator_1_TerminationAttempts.Terminator_1",
            "ns" : "HS4XC.CDRs"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "TerminationAttempts.Terminator" : 1,
                    "Originator" : 1
            },
            "name" : "TerminationAttempts.Terminator_1_Originator_1",
            "ns" : "HS4XC.CDRs"
    }
```

So you can see I have an index on the Date object.

Here is a sample document in the collection (with company data obscured):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5577e072e988475f14b9a159"),
    "CallID" : "BW090000946100615-1715027548@XX.XX.XX.XX",
    "Date" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z"),
    "CallSetupTime" : NumberLong(36400),
    "CallPDD" : NumberLong(324),
    "TerminationAttempts" : [
            {
                    "TermID" : "1234",
                    "Attempt" : NumberLong(1),
                    "DisconnectReason" : "503",
                    "TermCallSetupTime" : NumberLong(324),
                    "Media" : "XC RTP Proxy2",
                    "RoutingGroupID" : "0",
                    "ToIP" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
                    "TermSrcID" : "5",
                    "BsideIP" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
                    "TermPDD" : NumberLong(324),
                    "Terminator" : "terminator_name",
                    "RoutingResponse" : "sip34655938784@XX.XX.XX.XX;orig=1896;rate=1071;term=9035;cost=1071;fed=2,467;cliValid=0;Spam-Score=0;Test-No=0",
                    "ModifyTS" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:09Z"),
                    "RouteType" : "0"
            },
            {
                    "MatchedRoutingPrefix" : "346",
                    "TermCallSetupTime" : NumberLong(36075),
                    "Media" : "XC RTP Proxy2",
                    "TermSrcID" : "1",
                    "TermPDD" : NumberLong(3545),
                    "RingingType" : "D",
                    "RoutingResponse" : "sip34655938784@.XX.XX.XX.XX;orig=1896;rate=1071;term=9035;cost=1071;fed=2,467;cliValid=0;Spam-Score=0;Test-No=0",
                    "FinalToNumber" : "+555-555-5555",
                    "RouteType" : "0",
                    "TermID" : "7472",
                    "Attempt" : NumberLong(2),
                    "DisconnectReason" : "487",
                    "RoutingGroupID" : "56",
                    "ToIP" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
                    "BsideIP" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
                    "Terminator" : "terminator_name",
                    "ModifyTS" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:48Z")
            }
    ],
    "LocationName" : "Spain",
    "OrigToNumber" : "+555-555-5555",
    "CreatorID" : "16120",
    "Authentication" : "XX.XX.XX.XX",
    "Aside" : "XC Opensips A Side",
    "UserID" : "GAA-Z",
    "Originator" : "Originator_name",
    "ToNumber" : "555-555-5555",
    "CountryID" : "807",
    "UserGroupID" : "1896",
    "LocationID" : "14530",
    "FederationID" : "0",
    "PDD" : NumberLong(9219)
}
```

So if I run this query it is very fast:

```
db.CDRs.aggregate([
{$match: {"Date": {"$gte": new Date("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z")} } },
{$unwind: '$TerminationAttempts'},
{$group: {
    _id: {"Originator": "$Originator"}, 
    "minutes": {$sum: "$TerminationAttempts.Duration" }
}}
])
```

But if I run this query it takes hours

```
db.CDRs.aggregate([
{$match: {"Date": {"$gte": new Date("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z"), "$lt": new Date("2015-06-10T07:10:00Z") } } },
{$unwind: '$TerminationAttempts'},
{$group: {
    _id: {"Originator": "$Originator"}, 
    "minutes": {$sum: "$TerminationAttempts.Duration" }
}}
])
```

Lastly here is the explain of the slow query:

```
{
    "stages" : [
            {
                    "$cursor" : {
                            "query" : {
                                    "Date" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z"),
                                            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:10:00Z")
                                    }
                            },
                            "fields" : {
                                    "Originator" : 1,
                                    "TerminationAttempts" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                            },
                            "queryPlanner" : {
                                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                    "namespace" : "HS4XC.CDRs",
                                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                    "parsedQuery" : {
                                            "$and" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "Date" : {
                                                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:10:00Z")
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                            "Date" : {
                                                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z")
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "winningPlan" : {
                                            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                            "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                    "filter" : {
                                                            "Date" : {
                                                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z")
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    "inputStage" : {
                                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                                    "Date" : 1,
                                                                    "CallID" : 1,
                                                                    "TerminationAttempts.Attempt" : 1
                                                            },
                                                            "indexName" : "Date_1_CallID_1_TerminationAttempts.Attempt_1",
                                                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                                    "Date" : [
                                                                            "(true, new Date(1433920200000))"
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "CallID" : [
                                                                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "TerminationAttempts.Attempt" : [
                                                                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                    ]
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    },
                                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                            }
                    }
            },
            {
                    "$unwind" : "$TerminationAttempts"
            },
            {
                    "$group" : {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "Originator" : "$Originator"
                            },
                            "minutes" : {
                                    "$sum" : "$TerminationAttempts.Duration"
                            }
                    }
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Help!

Comment: Just noting that the selected index contains a "MultiKey" value from inside the array. That isn't being used in this query, just the date. But I'd  suggest it possibly has an adverse effect on scanning for the end data. Can you possibly just create a "Date" only index, or at least leading with "Date" and no fields from the array. That will probably take hours to do by the sound of it. But I would suggest to at least try that on a smaller sample of the data somewhere else and time the differing results from doing so.

Comment: I must add that I wish all first posts ( and questions in general ) were as well detailed with relevant information such as this is.

Comment: @user3561036 I don't understand the index bounds for `Date` : `(true, new Date(1433920200000))` -- does that mean a scan from the "lowest date" up to "2015-06-10T07:10:00Z" ? Why the lower bound wouldn't be used here ?

Comment: @user3561036 I have no idea why that helped, but adding the additional index on the Date field alone made a huge difference.

Comment: To basically explain "why it helped" your index was "MutiKey" which means that each element of the array from each document makes up an index entry ( in a sense ). That adds a **lot** of overhead to things to scan, particularly when you are scanning only for "Date" from that compound index. In short n*(array entries) more things to scan when you don't need to.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux As a learning exercise read my comment.

Comment: @user3561036 That explanation makes senses. I had not been considering it because mongoDB's documentation seemed to indicate that Mutikey index should not be slower than single indexes when your query one uses the first element. It seems to make difference when I only use one bound in my query, but boy does it make a difference with a range. I invite you repost your suggestion as an answer so I can give you credit where due.

Comment: @user3561036 I understand why a multikey index is not efficient. But not why the query plan do not use the _lower bound_ of the range query. Maybe it is just my English comprehension that is not good enough ? Or, once again, maybe I don't clearly understand the `explain`output ? Anyway, for my own education  I'll be curious to see what range is considered when the OP run his query against the bare `{date: 1}` index...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I cannot post the new explain output as a comment. I will post it as an answer instead.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux The explain output throws a lot of people. But the "upper bound" is considered if you look closely `"(true, new Date(1433920200000))"` which is different from `filter`. It's just that there is a **lot** to go through before that bound is found.

Answer (score 0):

There was a request for the new explain output after the Date only index was added. Thanks @user3561036

```
{
    "stages" : [
            {
                    "$cursor" : {
                            "query" : {
                                    "Date" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z"),
                                            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:10:00Z")
                                    }
                            },
                            "fields" : {
                                    "Originator" : 1,
                                    "TerminationAttempts" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                            },
                            "queryPlanner" : {
                                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                    "namespace" : "HS4XC.CDRs",
                                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                    "parsedQuery" : {
                                            "$and" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "Date" : {
                                                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:10:00Z")
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                            "Date" : {
                                                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-10T07:00:00Z")
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "winningPlan" : {
                                            "stage" : "CACHED_PLAN",
                                            "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                    "inputStage" : {
                                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                                    "Date" : 1
                                                            },
                                                            "indexName" : "Date_1",
                                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                                    "Date" : [
                                                                            "[new Date(1433919600000), new Date(1433920200000))"
                                                                    ]
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    },
                                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                            }
                    }
            },
            {
                    "$unwind" : "$TerminationAttempts"
            },
            {
                    "$group" : {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "Originator" : "$Originator"
                            },
                            "minutes" : {
                                    "$sum" : "$TerminationAttempts.Duration"
                            }
                    }
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```